# Setting core data relationship reusing same object removes previous relation

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I am importing data from a web service, in such data I have a tree of categories.

For example:

Restaurants
     - Italian
     - Mexican
     - Steakhouse

In my model I have set a relation called ParentCategory with an inverse relation called Subcategories. Everything is good so far.

Now, when I am importing my categories I am doing something like this: (Note: My code does not look like this. I have changed it to exemplify my problem)

```
NSEntityDescription *categoryEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSDescription *parentCategory = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[categoryEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context]

//Then I actually set some values for parentCategory.
//Then create the subcategories. 

NSDescription *italianDescription = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[categoryEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[italianDescription objectForKey:@"Italian" forKey:@"name"];

//Set the relationship
[italianDescription objectForKey:parentCategory forKey:@"ParentCategory"];

//All this works great but then when 
NSEntityDescription *mexicanDescription = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[categoryEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[mexicanDescription objectForKey:@"Mexican" forKey:@"name"];
[mexicanDescription objectForKey:parentCategory forKey:@"ParentCategory"];
```

It seems like when that last line of code runs it removes the relation from "italianDescription", therefore after I save my context it shows like it doesn't have a parent category. I removed some data from my web service and only the last subcategory that I set the relation to parent category object X keeps it. All previous will loose it.

I checked the apple developer documentation and it doesn't really help. That being said, how can I overcome this? Or what would be a efficient way to import that with relations.

Comment: Please add to your question - the definition of your Category entity, and also your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are setting anything, the way to set values for NSManagedObjects is

```
setValue: forKey:
```

Instead of NSDescription*'s you should be using NSManagedObject*

You may want to look into subclassing your entities as it allows for much easier access and setting of properties. In which case it would be

```
MyCustomEntity* myobj=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyentityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Then you can set the values just by using it's properties with dot notation or messaging.  You can do this by selecting the entity in the core-data editor and then under Editor on the Menu bar there is an option to create a NSManagedObject subclass, after you create that you need to tell the entity that it has a custom class now. This is done in the right hand Utiliies bar under Entity there is a Class field, just enter the name of your new class and it should be set up.

Comment: I am setting relationships. After running my import information is into the database and only the last parent category relationship is there.

As far as I know, NSEntityDescription will take care of creating the managed object for me. Check the first block of code in 

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html

Comment: @Ares, Is your parent category a to-many relation ship? if it is a one to one, then setting it at the end would replace it's current value.

Comment: it is a one-to-one, one category can only have one parent category. The inverse (subcategories) is a to-many, since a category can have many subcategories. 

Actually, I just checked, and the inverse was set to one-to-one. :) That did it. Thank you cwieland. It's funny how sometimes we can overlook little simple things.

Comment: @Ares, Yeah no problem, those little arrows always seem to be the root of problems when dealing with core-data. best

Comment: Look at the block of sample code you referenced again. It's fine to use NSEntityDescription to create a managed object, but the return value of insertNewObjectForEntityForName is NSManagedObjectContext *. You are assigning it to NSDescription *.